# Table with identical submit button in every row: first submit button doesn't work (multiple same ids?)

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a table which show product's files. A file can have a note added. If a note was added, it is displayed in a row. If not, text area field with submit button is displayed instead.

Short story, it all works, except for the first row without a note. After typing a note and clicking submit button nothing happens.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="files-list" style="display: none">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>File</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:if test="${fn:length(bean.product.files)>0}"> 
                <c:forEach items="${bean.product.files}" var="na">
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/products/files/${na.id}.do">${na.name}</a></td>
                        <td><fmt:formatDate value="${na.created}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <c:if test="${empty na.note}">
                                <form:form id="${na.id}" method="POST" modelAttribute="bean" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/app/updateFile.ajax?id=${bean.product.id}&fileId=${na.id}" style="display: inline">                             
                                    <form:textarea path="prodFiles" rows="1" cols="50" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="version" value="${bean.product.version}">
                                    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Save it!" />
                                </form:form>    
                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${not empty na.note}">
                                <div style="max-width: 400px">${na.note}</div>                          
                            </c:if>
                        </td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="$().mkdelformTable('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/app/deleteFile.ajax?id=${bean.product.id}&fileId=${na.id}', this)">Delete it!</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
                </c:if>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**Possible hints:**

1. When I open the table (it's a pop-up) console shows multiple `[DOM] Found X elements with non-unique id` errors
2. Checking elements in dev's tools I noticed that the first row doesn't include the form part. Possibly connected with the multiple-same-ids problem. **Example:**

```
<td>                                                                
   <textarea id="prodFiles" name="prodFiles" rows="1" cols="50"></textarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="version" value="181">
   <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Save it!">
</td>

VS

<td>                            
   <form id="65" style="display: inline" action="/oferty/app/updateFile.ajax?id=12701&amp;fileId=65" method="POST">                             
      <textarea id="prodFiles" name="prodFiles" rows="1" cols="50"></textarea>
      <input type="hidden" name="version" value="181">
      <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Save it!">
   </form>  
</td>
```

**Edit:** Also, new files can be added so hard-coding different names/ids can't be done, if suggested.

Comment: If you already know which errors it has, why don't you try correcting the errors first and then seeing if it still behaves badly?

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure if THIS IS what is causing the problem, as for all the rows (except for the first one) it works. I tried checking the position of `form` tags, also putting it in a table, also changing the form to simple text input instead of text area. Also tried changing some ids adding file's id to them to make them unique.

Comment: I've begun thinking about ajax-ing it, but I'm not really familiar with front-end technologies :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out, there was some legacy code. I managed to get rid of 'multiple same ids' etc. errors by adding a note in an additional pop-up - on a previos page, instead of an input, I included a button to the new pop-up.